# Uploaded App to Android

Tags: android, upload

When I go to download my uploaded app from the play store, I click purchase and a message comes up "error please try again" I keep retrying it and I get the same message. I don't know what could be wrong. I uploaded everything correctly. It's published but for some reason I can't download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow [no place for such questions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). But I will try to help you.

1. Try to remove the test application (if debugged on the device)
2. Restart the device
3. Check with the other device
4. Try setting via a web interface
5. Try updating the android services

If your application paid

1. Check availability in your country in the list
2. Check the relevance of the payment card in Android Market

Comment: I do not understand you (